# How to know when bread/cake is bad

Tags: food-safety

I have recently opened a air tight package of castella. It, however, is expired by about a year and a half, but, other than being a little bit dry, it tastes fine. I have only tried a little bit. Is it safe to eat as long as there isn't mold, and does this apply to other breads/cakes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule around here is when in doubt, throw it out.

That said, personally, I doubt there is any issue, especially if only healthy people are eating it.  I've never heard of an age-related problem with cakes and breads other than mold which would be visible, or rancidity when the fats spoil from age which you can both smell and taste easily.